# How to search for an email address in Google

Tags: google-search

You know how there are operators and other functions to make Google Search easier… Is there such thing for searching email addresses?

For example, if you wanted to search in a website, you can type `site:`. But if you want to find an email addresses, you can't do `email address:` etc. Typing in `@` won't get you any email addresses either, as I don't think it's recognised as a search keyword.

---

Edit:
thank you for all your answers. I think I failed to get my point accross... Basically I want the search results to be only ones that have email addresses in them. But I don't know what the email address looks like.

For example, I want to find pages that have John Doe's email address. But I don't know what his email address is.

So I type "John Doe email address" in the search box and the search comes up with pages that actually have email addresses, but it also comes up with ones that just have the text "email and/or address".

The search would only show pages with actual email addresses if I could type in "@" in search and Google recognizes this as part of an email address. But Google does not work that way, so I was wondering if there is an alternative.

Ok maybe I should have asked a new question instead of adding this here... What do you think?

Comment: Here are some guidlines http://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2009/09/23/find-anyones-personal-email may be this might get you with some idea.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose email address between double quotes. I.E. to find web pages that have the email address to use to send doodle proposals to Google write  "proposals@google.com" in the search box.

Answer (score 1):

> When you put a word or phrase in quotes, the results will only include
>   pages with the same words in the same order as the ones inside the
>   quotes. Only use this if you're looking for an exact word or phrase,
>   otherwise you'll exclude many helpful results by mistake.

Example: "imagine all the people"

This page here " [https://support.google.com/......](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=e) " Contains the Google search operators, and as it looks like, there is no option to search for emails, but you could use quotations, i tried with my email and it came back with About 543 results. All matches:

Example: Someone@gmail.com.

Comment: The link no longer contains a complete list of search operators.